# Can I set a default picture for all contacts added later?

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook

RT, I want to set a default picture for contacts I added later.
Can I do this using the public APIs?

Comment: you add contact by AddressBook framework or other type,if not then which type you add contact?

Comment: just add contact with Contact app coming with ios

Comment: but by application or other way,give clear idea,what you try ?

Comment: I just want to know can I do something in my application then after that contacts added by user with the native "Contact" app of ios have a default picture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a photo later.  This is a code fragment that will load a photo based on a URL.

> ```
>   image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
>   if (image && [image isValid]) {
>       [abPerson setImageData:[image TIFFRepresentation]];
>   }
> ```

Address Book has no notion of a 'default' picture, but you can certainly use this mechanism to load the same picture for any contact that doesn't have their own picture.